# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. - Flutter app

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, jvm

Trying to build a flutter app after some dependency upgrades. Getting this:

```
hat went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[        ] > error: invalid source release: 17
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[        ]  at ....
```

I've tried changing the build.gradle and JVM targets but no luck.

I've removed and updated the JVM and tried to modify different gradle/kotlin but get the same error. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It seems dependency upgrade are not in sync with your JAVA version. Have you tried updating gradle to version 8 or greater in the build.gradle file or setting your  JAVA version environment variable to 17 as specified? Also can you mention your java, gradle versions, dependencies that you updated?

Comment: Hey @AashisShrestha - Honestly, i'm so stuck :) 

So i switched my JVM to

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.9 (JetBrains s.r.o. 17.0.9+7-b1087.7)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

When i check my gradle.build file it 'looks' ok - but i guess not?